# Проверка существования таблицы в БД средствами Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый день, интересует вопрос как средствами Entity Framework проверить на существование таблицу в БД, база `SQL` пустая, в App.config прописан `connectionstring`. Подход CodeFirst. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Делаете запрос на теблицу - если всё упало - таблицы нет. Но вообще при CodeFirst схема бд должна генериться программно, а изменения в схеме накатываются миграциями.

Comment: @tym32167, CodeFirst прекрасно и без автомиграций работает.

Comment: Мне просто DataSource заполнять при загрузке формы изначально надо знать точно, есть или нет в бд таблица

Comment: юзайте CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: да вот именно хотелось как-то может избежать той конструкции но видно не получится

Comment: @free_ze я и не утверждал обратного.

Comment: @RomanIeromenko а чем вам эта конструкция не нравится?

Comment: Ну нравится не нравится прийдется использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что можно использовать `SqlQuery` для запуска скрипта с выборкой в нужной таблице, вот пример:

```
var tableName = "TableName";  // имя таблицы базы данных
var schemaName = "SchemaName"; // имя схемы базы данных

bool isExists = context.Database
     .SqlQuery<int?>(@"
         SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables AS tabs
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sch ON tabs.schema_id = sch.schema_id
         WHERE sch.Name = '" + schemaName + "' AND tabs.Name = '" + tableName + "'")
     .SingleOrDefault() != null;
```

Логика достаточно простая ищем в таблицах нужную нам таблицу по имени и в схемах нужную схему данных. Если `SingleOrDefault` вернет результат, то будет не `null`, в противном случае `null` - значит таблицы нет. Нужно просто составить правильный SQL запрос.

Ссылка на источник ответа: [Entity Framework - How to check if table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6101106/5275890)

Полезные ссылки:

- [`sys.tables` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187406(v=sql.120).aspx)
- [`sys.schemas` (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms176011(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

В принципе как выяснил можно обойтись без всяких проверок:

```
 using (DealerContext db = new DealerContext())
        {
            db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();                

            db.Database.Initialize(false);                
            //               
        }
```

db.Database.Initialize(false) проверяет наличие таблицы в БД, если нет - добавляет все таблицы из контекста. Очень здорово